# How to flatten columns of type array of structs (as returned by Spark ML API)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

Maybe it's just because I'm relatively new to the API, but I feel like Spark ML methods often return DFs that are unnecessarily difficult to work with.

This time, it's the ALS model that's tripping me up. Specifically, the recommendForAllUsers method. Let's reconstruct the type of DF it would return:

```scala
scala> val arrayType = ArrayType(new StructType().add("itemId", IntegerType).add("rating", FloatType))

scala> val recs = Seq((1, Array((1, .7), (2, .5))), (2, Array((0, .9), (4, .1)))).
  toDF("userId", "recommendations").
  select($"userId", $"recommendations".cast(arrayType))

scala> recs.show()
```

```
+------+------------------+
|userId|   recommendations|
+------+------------------+
|     1|[[1,0.7], [2,0.5]]|
|     2|[[0,0.9], [4,0.1]]|
+------+------------------+
```

```scala
scala> recs.printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- userId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- itemId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

Now, I only care about the `itemId` in the `recommendations` column. After all, the method is `recommendForAllUsers` not `recommendAndScoreForAllUsers` (ok ok I'll stop being sassy...)

How do I do this??

I thought I had it when I created a UDF:

```scala
scala> val itemIds = udf((arr: Array[(Int, Float)]) => arr.map(_._1))
```

but that produces an error:

```
scala> recs.withColumn("items", items($"recommendations"))
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(recommendations)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<struct<_1:int,_2:float>> type, however, '`recommendations`' is of array<struct<itemId:int,rating:float>> type.;;
'Project [userId#87, recommendations#92, UDF(recommendations#92) AS items#238]
+- Project [userId#87, cast(recommendations#88 as array<struct<itemId:int,rating:float>>) AS recommendations#92]
   +- Project [_1#84 AS userId#87, _2#85 AS recommendations#88]
      +- LocalRelation [_1#84, _2#85]
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

wow, my coworker came up with an extremely elegant solution:

```
scala> recs.select($"userId", $"recommendations.itemId").show
+------+------+
|userId|itemId|
+------+------+
|     1|[1, 2]|
|     2|[0, 4]|
+------+------+
```

So maybe the Spark ML API isn't that difficult after all :)

Answer (score 5):

With an array as the type of a column, e.g. `recommendations`, you'd be quite productive using [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function (or the more advanced flatMap operator).

> **explode(e: Column): Column** Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

That gives you bare structs to work with.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val structType = new StructType().
  add($"itemId".int).
  add($"rating".float)
val arrayType = ArrayType(structType)
val recs = Seq((1, Array((1, .7), (2, .5))), (2, Array((0, .9), (4, .1)))).
  toDF("userId", "recommendations").
  select($"userId", $"recommendations" cast arrayType)

val exploded = recs.withColumn("recs", explode($"recommendations"))
scala> exploded.show
+------+------------------+-------+
|userId|   recommendations|   recs|
+------+------------------+-------+
|     1|[[1,0.7], [2,0.5]]|[1,0.7]|
|     1|[[1,0.7], [2,0.5]]|[2,0.5]|
|     2|[[0,0.9], [4,0.1]]|[0,0.9]|
|     2|[[0,0.9], [4,0.1]]|[4,0.1]|
+------+------------------+-------+
```

structs are nice in `select` operator with `*` (star) to flatten them to columns per the struct fields.

You could do `select($"element.*")`.

```
scala> exploded.select("userId", "recs.*").show
+------+------+------+
|userId|itemId|rating|
+------+------+------+
|     1|     1|   0.7|
|     1|     2|   0.5|
|     2|     0|   0.9|
|     2|     4|   0.1|
+------+------+------+
```

I think that could do what you're after.

---

p.s. Stay away from UDFs as long as possible since they "trigger" row conversion from the internal format (`InternalRow`) to JVM objects that can lead to excessive GCs.